# Can not read xml file via Javascript in html site

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, apache

I have an xml file like this:

```
<Values>
    <Sample1>
        <Sensor1 value="45" Time="19:26:33" />
        <Sensor2 value="40" Time="19:26:33" />
        <Sensor3 value="37" Time="19:26:33" />
        <Sensor4 value="33" Time="19:26:33" />
    </Sample1>
    <Sample2>
        <Sensor1 value="19" Time="19:26:34" />
        <Sensor2 value="43" Time="19:26:34" />
        <Sensor3 value="50" Time="19:26:34" />
        <Sensor4 value="29" Time="19:26:34" />
    </Sample2>
    <Sample3>
        <Sensor1 value="28" Time="19:26:35" />
        <Sensor2 value="44" Time="19:26:35" />
        <Sensor3 value="35" Time="19:26:35" />
        <Sensor4 value="24" Time="19:26:35" />
    </Sample3>
    <Sample4>
        <Sensor1 value="35" Time="19:26:36" />
        <Sensor2 value="55" Time="19:26:36" />
        <Sensor3 value="27" Time="19:26:36" />
        <Sensor4 value="36" Time="19:26:36" />
    </Sample4>
</Values>
```

and I need to read the data on my website. I have tried many ways that i found online for reading the xml, but nothing works. I can not take the value and the time of my data. I am new in xml and javascript but its been two weeks since I'm searching and reading every day, but with no effect. 
(My xml is placed in the same folder with the website. )

Comment: Can you include some of the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("File.xml", {}, function (xml){

                var allNodes = xml.documentElement.childNodes;
                $(allNodes).each(function (i, sample) {

                    if ($(sample).prop("tagName")) {

                        var sensors = sample.childNodes;

                        $(sensors).each(function (i, sensor) {
                            if ($(sensor).prop("tagName")) {
                                console.log($(sensor).attr("value"));
                                console.log($(sensor).attr("Time"));
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })

            });
        });
```

This will read all the sensors within each sample and logs the value and time attributes of each sensor .. Its using Jquery as well ... Hope this helps ...

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I include jquery in Sublime Text, I rename the file.xml with mine, but nothing..